# Using getopt for required arguments

Tags: c, arguments, getopt

I currently have code that looks like this:

```
while (( flags = getopt(argc, argv, "abc")) != -1){
    switch(flags){
    case 'a':
        dflag = 1;
        break;
    case 'b':
        rflag = 1;
        break;
    case 'c':
        cflag = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is I wanted to include something like testprogram -c -d 1

Where c is required to handle the -d, without -c, testprogram -d 1 will just run without arguments.

I tried a large variety of things and I just can't seem to get this to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remind me not to have to debug the code that uses variable `dflag` for the `-a` option and the variable `rflag` for the `-b` option.

Comment: @Jonathan: And then you went and debugged it...  You needed reminding after just 8 minutes?

Comment: I simply did a global search and replace.  If I'm using `xflag` notation, the `x` and the `-x` match.  Otherwise, I'll use longer, more meaningful names for the control variables which do not necessarily correlate with the option letters.  An additional concern with the outline is 'if `dflag` is used when `-a` is specified, what variable will be set when `-d` is passed by the user after entering `-c`?'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two options available to you, one of which will work and one of which may or may not work.

The 'may or may not work' option would be exemplified by:

```
char *opts = "abc";
char *opts_d = "abcd:";

while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, opts)) != -1)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
    case 'a':
        aflag = 1;
        break;
    case 'b':
        bflag = 1;
        break;
    case 'c':
        cflag = 1;
        opts = opts_d;
        break;
    case 'd':
        dflag = 1;
        dvalue = optarg;
        break;
    default:
        ...error handling...
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether there's anything that prohibits you from changing the list of valid options on successive calls to [`getopt()][1]`, but I do know it is not normally done to change the options as you go.  So, treat with caution.  Note that if the `-c` option is never found, the `opt` value of `d` will never be returned by `getopt()`, so that code will not be executed otherwise.  Note that if the user enters a `-d` option before the `-c`, `getopt()` will report an invalid option when it processes the `-d`.  You can control the error reporting; you would probably have to.  (The `optopt` variable contains the actual option letter that was encountered as invalid.)

The 'will work' option is:

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "abcd:")) != -1)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
    case 'a':
        aflag = 1;
        break;
    case 'b':
        bflag = 1;
        break;
    case 'c':
        cflag = 1;
        break;
    case 'd':
        if (cflag == 0)
            ...report error about must use -c option before -d option...
        dflag = 1;
        dvalue = optarg;
        break;
    default:
        ...error handling...
        break;
    }
}
```